# "Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined"

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

all,

I'm working with the following HTML/Javascript code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- google fonts from CDN -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- highcharts -->
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 95%;
            margin: auto;
            font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
        }
        #chart_container {
            width:100%;
            height:500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Live Data</h1>
    <div id="chart_container">

    </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart_container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                events: {
                    load: getBirds
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'DRHW Live Data Stream'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Count Observed'
                }
            },
            series: [
            ],
            legend: {
                layout: 'horiztonal',
                align: 'center'
            }
        });
        function getBirds() {
            var now = new Date();
            var et = now.getTime() / 1000; //PHP TS
            var st = et - 10; //30 seconds prior in PHP
            console.log(chart);
            if (chart.series.length > 0) {
                var series = chart.series[0];
                var length = series.length + 1;
                var shift = series.data.length > 20;
            }
            $.getJSON("https://path/to/json&callback=?", function(result) {
                var data = result.data;if (data.length == 0) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    additions = new Array();
                    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        if (data[i].qstype != "1") {
                            species = data[i].answers[0]['answer'];
                            scode = species.substring(0,species.search(" - ")).trim()
                            count = (data[i].answers[1]['answer'] * 1);
                            newdata = new Object();
                            newdata['name'] = species;
                            newdata['count'] = count;
                            additions.push(newdata);
                        }
                    }
                    //now, for each addition, you need to loop through the existing data structures, and see if the thing exists.  if it does, add the data; if not, add the thing, then add the data.
                    var existingdata = chart.series;
                    for (i=0;i<additions.length;i++) {
                        isnewpoint = true;
                        for (j=0;j<existingdata.length;j++) {
                            if (existingdata[j].name == additions[i].name) {
                                isnewpoint = false
                                count = additions[i].count;
                                point = [now.getTime(),count];
                                chart.series[j].addPoint(point, true, shift);
                                shift = false; //this way, only one shift occurs - the first time through adding a new point to an existing data set. this will control against future shifting, either from other datapoints having new points added, 
                            }
                        }
                        if (isnewpoint) {
                            newseries = new Object();
                            count = additions[i].count;
                            newseries['name'] = additions[i].name;
                            for (j=0;j<length;j++) {
                                newseries['data'].push(0);
                            }
                            newseries['data'].push(count);
                            chart.series.push(newseries);
                        }
                    }
                    //we have now looped through and added a new data point to all species where new data was created in this pull.  We still need to add a new point to those that were not affected.
                    existingdata = chart.series;
                    for (i=0;i<existingdata.length;i++) {
                        getname = existingdata[i].name;
                        getlength = existingdata[i].data.length;
                        if (getlength<length) { //which we established earlier as one MORE than existed previously, prior to the addition
                            point = [now.getTime(),0]
                            chart.series[i].addPoint(point, true, shift);
                        }
                    }
                }
                setTimeout(getBirds,10000);
            });
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

The problem that I'm having is pretty straightforward (but driving me nuts!), and early on in the js block.  Though I'm defining the variable 'chart' as the new Highcharts chart, and I'm setting 'getBirds' as the function to load once that's loaded, the console.log line tells me that the chart is undefined, and the line below it throws an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'series' of undefined`).

I've checked the following:

1. The Highcharts reference (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-live-data), which suggests a setup similar to mine;
2. I've tried defining the `chart` variable on its own line (which of course defines chart for my console.log, but does not define the `chart.series` required on the next line);
3. I've researched stackoverflow and other docs for variable scope, but I think I'm handling it properly based on my research.
4. I've tried reversing the order - putting the `getBirds()` function above the `chart` definition.

I'm at a loss.  Any help provided is much appreciated; thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have---> `$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Yes, OP, `$(function(){})` and `$(document).ready(function(){})` are the same thing.

Comment: Regarding your issue, if the `chart.events.load` handler is for waiting until the DOM is ready, then why use it? You're already doing that (twice).

Comment: I didn't think I needed both, but I wanted to follow the syntax I've seen elsewhere as exactly as possible.  I'll edit and remove the `$function() {}` declaration at top, for clarity.

Comment: @BlueSkies, the reason I'm using chart.events.load is because I need to instantiate my live data chain.  `getBirds()` is designed to populate the chart with data, so I wait for the chart to be loaded, call it, and then let it call itself to make the loop permanent.

Comment: @BlueSkies `chart.events.load` waits until chart is rendered, not DOM. Using twice `$(doc).ready()` is not the culprit also. kcbaker - could you recreate issue on your website? I would like to see that error live. Are you sure that error comes from line below your `console.log()`?

Comment: @PawełFus: My point was that it seems clear that the `events.load` handler is firing immediately, and synchronously, which means that there's no chance for the object to be returned to the `chart` variable before the handler fires. If this is the case, then that means the chart is rendered immediately, and there's no need for an event handler. If so, OP should just run the code directly after the `chart` assignment. That way `chart` will be instantiated and fully usable.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that - there is no assignment for chart variable, should be: `function getBirds() { var chart = this; var now = new Date(); ... `

Comment: @PawełFus - I'm eager to try your solution.  I'm stuck on another project, but I'll update here later tonight with what I find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is likely that you cannot refer to a variable during its stages of declaration. I'm guessing that the load function is being called as it's being declared. Luckily, you can refer to the object during the function declaration. Try the following block of code.

```
function getBirds(e) {
    var now = new Date(),
        et = now.getTime() / 1000, //PHP TS
        st = et - 10, //30 seconds prior in PHP
        chart = this;
    if (chart.series.length > 0) {
```

...declaring the `chart` variable in the var block inside.

Comment: This was really helpful, @pyius.  The only other challenge was getting the timeout right, but the trick there is to do `setTimeout(function(){getBirds(e)},10000)` to get that to fire every 10 seconds.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: how to do it in yii2? can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255144/yii2-chart-is-not-defined)?

Answer (score 1):

Trying out examples from highchart page I found out that variable `chart` is available only after `$.json()` or `$ajax()` call. If you try to use `chart` before that it returns `undefined`. Because it is and it is set only after $.json().

Their examples with json or ajax are set this way:

```
var chart;

function requestData() {...}

$(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart_container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
   ...
});
```

I did similarly with your example. From `getBirds()` I commented out some lines before json call:

```
        console.log(chart);
        if (chart.series.length > 0) {
            var series = chart.series[0];
            var length = series.length + 1;
            var shift = series.data.length > 20;
        }
```

and moved them after json call.

And changed this line:

```
                    //newdata['name'] = species;
                    newdata['name'] = scode;
```

And stop here:

```
                    for (j=0;j<length;j++) {
```

because of error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

at line

```
newseries['data'].push(count);
```

It fails because there is no array. Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

the **function declaration** is interpreted before the chart object exists in the global namespace.

If you change the syntax to a **function expression** instead

```
var getBirds=function() {
    ....
};
```

it won't be evaluated until you call it.

However, you might want to add chart as a parameter for getBirds(), it's a little cheaper than getting a variable from the global namespace.

**EDIT**

This might require a bit of debugging, but it's worth a try

```
    var getBirds = function(chart) {
               ...
            };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart_container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                events: {
                    load: function() { 
                                     getBirds(this); 
                                     }
                }
            }
            ...
        });

        setTimeout(getBirds,10000);
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: This will rise new error: `ReferenceError: getBirds is not defined` on script's line 8. Basically, it's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @Pavlo: Actually it won't. The variable declaration will be hoisted, so it'll be getting the default initialization, which is `undefined`. I don't know exactly what that property is for, but if it's for DOM ready, then OP should just get rid of the function, and run the code immediately.

Comment: @Pavlo you can declare getBirds before jQuery document ready event, but that's another matther entirely, and an irrelevant comment, by the way.

Comment: Indeed, I've just cheked it and no error is shown, but you still can't do that, `chart.events.load` will be `undefined`: http://jsbin.com/ABUnEhe/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Amenadiel, I tried your method, and while it doesn't throw an error anymore, it doesn't appear to execute the function.  Since the function is called in the chart's `events.load`, if I change the syntax to a function expression, the function appears never to be called.

Comment: Please see my edit to original post. You can also try using your original syntax for the function declaration, just remember keeping chart as a parameter instead of looking for it in the global namespace.

Answer (score -1):

You should check two solution :

1. series variable property Shouldn't be empty array
   maybe its ok to enter series: null;
2. replace your script with this code and check it again :

http://notepad.cc/share/3TwgCoEano

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'chart_container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                events: {
                    load: getBirds
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'DRHW Live Data Stream'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Count Observed'
                }
            },
            series: null,
            legend: {
                layout: 'horiztonal',
                align: 'center'
            }
        });
        function getBirds() {
            var now = new Date();
            var et = now.getTime() / 1000; //PHP TS
            var st = et - 10; //30 seconds prior in PHP
            console.log(chart);
            if (chart.series.length > 0) {
                var series = chart.series[0];
                var length = series.length + 1;
                var shift = series.data.length > 20;
            }
            $.getJSON("https://path/to/json&callback=?", function(result) {
                var data = result.data;if (data.length == 0) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    additions = new Array();
                    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        if (data[i].qstype != "1") {
                            species = data[i].answers[0]['answer'];
                            scode = species.substring(0,species.search(" - ")).trim()
                            count = (data[i].answers[1]['answer'] * 1);
                            newdata = new Object();
                            newdata['name'] = species;
                            newdata['count'] = count;
                            additions.push(newdata);
                        }
                    }
                    //now, for each addition, you need to loop through the existing data structures, and see if the thing exists.  if it does, add the data; if not, add the thing, then add the data.
                    var existingdata = chart.series;
                    for (i=0;i<additions.length;i++) {
                        isnewpoint = true;
                        for (j=0;j<existingdata.length;j++) {
                            if (existingdata[j].name == additions[i].name) {
                                isnewpoint = false
                                count = additions[i].count;
                                point = [now.getTime(),count];
                                chart.series[j].addPoint(point, true, shift);
                                shift = false; //this way, only one shift occurs - the first time through adding a new point to an existing data set. this will control against future shifting, either from other datapoints having new points added, 
                            }
                        }
                        if (isnewpoint) {
                            newseries = new Object();
                            count = additions[i].count;
                            newseries['name'] = additions[i].name;
                            for (j=0;j<length;j++) {
                                newseries['data'].push(0);
                            }
                            newseries['data'].push(count);
                            chart.series.push(newseries);
                        }
                    }
                    //we have now looped through and added a new data point to all species where new data was created in this pull.  We still need to add a new point to those that were not affected.
                    existingdata = chart.series;
                    for (i=0;i<existingdata.length;i++) {
                        getname = existingdata[i].name;
                        getlength = existingdata[i].data.length;
                        if (getlength<length) { //which we established earlier as one MORE than existed previously, prior to the addition
                            point = [now.getTime(),0]
                            chart.series[i].addPoint(point, true, shift);
                        }
                    }
                }
                setTimeout(getBirds,10000);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Vahid.  I tried your code, which it looks like just replaces the series definition will null instead of empty array (let me know if I missed anything), but no dice.