# Yii2 Chart is not defined

Tags: javascript, charts, yii2, chart.js, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to show some data on the chart while using `Yii2`. I have installed [Yii2 Chart JS](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/practically/yii2-chartjs) via the composer. Below is the code is taken from the documentation

```
use practically\chartjs\Chart;

Chart::widget([
    'type' => Chart::TYPE_BAR,
    'datasets' => [
        [
            'data' => [
                'Label 1' => 10,
                'Label 2' => 20,
                'Label 3' => 30
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Now when I refreshed this page I not seeing any chart. But in `inspect->console` I am getting an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined

**Update 1**

Here is my [composer.lock](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hFCpMHJbo0-2rRaVq_3_gQThjtBS7Pnp/view?usp=sharing) file

I have looked into this issue and found some solutions but still unable to perform the task.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you installed package? Did you see it in vendor

Comment: @DenisOstrovsky yes it's properly installed and in vendor it's there

Answer (score 0):

To display chart you must `echo` result of widget

```
echo Chart::widget([
    'type' => Chart::TYPE_BAR,
    'datasets' => [
        [
            'data' => [
                'Label 1' => 10,
                'Label 2' => 20,
                'Label 3' => 30
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: with `echo` I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined`

Comment: Are you run `composer require bower-asset/chart-js` before? Like it says in [readme](https://github.com/Practically/yii2-chartjs#installation)

Comment: add here whole view file and composer.lock

Comment: And your whole view file please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211887/discussion-between-faisal-and-denis-ostrovsky).